# AWS Lambda Error while running gulp build command

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, gulp, serverless-framework

i am working on a legacy AWS lambda project with serverless framework, now when i run npm install command or trying to update the gulp version from 3 to 4, i am getting this error can someone please explain me what is the issue, as am a beginner in using NodeJs, Gulp , AWS Lambda and Serverless framework. Below am attaching the screenshot of error and the package.json file from the project. Can someone please help.

[image]

This is the package.json:

```
{  
  "name": "test-cloud-services",
  "version": "1.8.0r1", 
  "main": "test.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "coverage": "istanbul cover node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha -- dist/test",
    "ci-coverage": "istanbul cover --report cobertura node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha dist/test -- -R mocha-junit-reporter",
    "deploy": "gulp deploy"
  },  
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-iot-device-sdk": "^2.2.13",
    "bluebird": "3.4.6",
    "dotenv": "2.0.0",
    "elasticsearch": "^16.7.3",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "fast-csv": "^4.3.6",
    "http-aws-es": "^6.0.0",
    "inversify": "3.3.0",
    "json-templater": "1.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "node-fetch": "^2.7.0",
    "punycode": "^2.3.1",
    "randomstring": "1.1.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "request": "2.87.0",
    "request-promise-native": "^0.0.0",
    "serverless-plugin-split-stacks": "^1.13.0",
    "serverless-plugin-write-env-vars": "1.0.1",
    "uuid": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/aws-iot-device-sdk": "^2.2.8",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "0.0.6",
    "@types/chai": "3.4.35",
    "@types/colors": "1.1.3",
    "@types/elasticsearch": "5.0.25",
    "@types/http-aws-es": "1.1.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.116",
    "@types/mocha": "2.2.40",
    "@types/node": "7.0.4",
    "@types/randomstring": "1.1.5",
    "@types/sinon": "2.1.2",
    "@types/uuid": "3.4.2",
    "@types/yargs": "10.0.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1505.0",
    "chai": "3.5.0",
    "colors": "1.3.1",
    "cross-env": "3.1.3",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-install": "0.6.0",
    "gulp-shell": "0.5.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "2.6.4",
    "gulp-strip-code": "0.1.4",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.12.2",
    "istanbul": "0.4.5",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "mocha-junit-reporter": "1.17.0",
    "mocha-typescript": "^1.1.14",
    "mz": "2.4.0",
    "prettier": "1.14.2",
    "proxyquire": "1.7.11",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "serverless-offline": "^13.3.0",
    "serverless-prune-plugin": "^2.0.2",
    "shared-components": "../shared",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.5",
    "sinon": "1.17.7",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "yargs": "^17.7.2"
  }
}
```

It would be really helpful if someone can explain me how i can resolve this issue.